# AJAX get method doesn't work on second click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, modal-dialog

I am using jQuery v1.7.2.

The following code generates applicable checkboxes in bootstrap (2.2.1) modal form:

```
    $sql1="Select $sub_listing_id,$sub_listing_name FROM $sub_listing";
    $results=$wpdb->get_results($sql1,ARRAY_A);

    $html_code= '<form id="multiselect">';
    $num=0;
    foreach($results as $key=>$value)
    {
        foreach($value as $k1=>$v1)
        {        
            if($k1==$sub_listing_id)
            {
                $sub_listing_id_val=$v1;
            }
            if($k1==$sub_listing_name)
            {
                $sub_listing_name_val=$v1;

    $html_code.= '<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="'.$sub_listing_id_val.'">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$sub_listing_name_val.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    $num=$num + 1;
    if($num%5==0)
    $html_code.= '<br/><br/>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html_code.= '</form>';
    echo $html_code;
```

Now, i select some checkboxes and pass the selected values through the following jQuery:

```
$('#btn-add-sub-listing-save').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ajax_url='add_sub-listing.php';
    var dataString=$('#multiselect').serialize();
    showLoader('.modal-body');
    dataString=dataString.replace(/&/g,' AND ');

    $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url + '?' + dataString,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
        $('.modal-body').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

If i edit the jQuery:

```
$('.modal-body').html(dataString);
```

it works just fine. This means #multiselect gets serialized all the time, but it won't get appended second time onwards. So, i can't get the values on mu landing page and hence can't progress.

I have used cache: false and async:false. Still, it won't work!
Please give your suggestions.

Maybe the bootstrap-modal-cache has something to do with this.
I had overcome this situation before by using the following jQuery:

```
$('.btn-add-sub-listing').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#add-sub-listing-modal').removeData("modal");
    $('#add-sub-listing-modal').modal({remote: $(this).attr("href")})
    $('#add-sub-listing-modal').modal('show');

});
```

Here, i used "href". Can i do it for buttons where "href" doesn't apply?

Comment: Be very careful! This line looks like you are generating an SQL query client side! Injection! `dataString=dataString.replace(/&/g,' AND ');`

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely, when you replace the HTML, replacing the button with a new button which will unwire the click event.

You should rewire the click event each time you replace the HTML contents, or use the [jQuery `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to wire the event. This will work with whatever button element you have matching under `body` at the time the event is fired.

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn-add-sub-listing-save', function(e)
{
    // handler as before
});
```

Comment: What actually happens? Does it hit the click handler?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Temp variable and check it before ajax is

Comment: If i edit the jQuery:

$('.modal-body').html(dataString);
it works just fine. This means #multiselect gets serialized all the time, but it won't get appended second time onwards. So, i can't get the values on mu landing page and hence can't progress.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$('body').on('click', '#btn', function(e)
{
    // you code here
});
```